# how to convert .xls to .csv using cakephp

Tags: csv, cakephp-2.0, xls, xlsx

I am new to cakephp and I need to convert ".xls" file to ".csv" file using cakephp2.0. I tried by taking PhpExcel even though it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

first download the Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader class, save it inside vendor folder

before starting the controller class add the following

```
App::uses('Vendor', 'excel_reader');
```

inside the function

```
  public function createcsvfromxls() {

    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(WWW_ROOT . 'pathtofile.xls', true);
     ob_clean();
    if ($filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "csv")) {
        if ($file = fopen($filename, "w")) {
            fputcsv($file, array('column 1', 'column 2'));
        }
        $exeldata = $data->sheets['0']['cells'];
        foreach ($exeldata as $key => $val) {
            fputcsv($file, array('columonedata', 'colum2data'));
        }
    }


    fclose($file);
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=DHAProviderdetails.csv");
    header("charset: UTF-8");
    echo readfile($filename);
    unlink($filename);
    exit;
  }
```

try this

Comment: Thankq harikrish for your reply and for xlsx  to csv  also we need to follow same criteria ahh....